# Need help regarding Test Management tool Testlink

Tags: testing, testlink

Our company is small and in a project only 1 or 2 testers are assigned. And our all test related things are maintained on Excels sheets. And for bug tracking we are using Mantis. We create test cases on Excel sheet and execute them via same.

Is TestLink or any other test management tool will be helpful to us or not. As number of testers are less so there are no merging of test cases are done. Only one QA develop test cases and execute it. Please suggest me if it will be any help to us or not.

If so please suggest only free application

Answer (score 0):

I am working for a startup and we are pretty much using Testlink. Our QA team is always pretty small (in between 1-3). It's very helpful for organizing and keeping the test cases for your whole system. It becomes more useful when you go for a release. You can assign your testers based on a test build so that they can go through test cases one after another and mark which tests are passing or not. Finally, you can generate report based on those for your build.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but as I mentioned in our QA team only one tester is assigned with one project so ... no such thing as merging or anything is going on here. As I have learned that Test management tool is for managing test cases made by multiple QA for same application. That's y i asked

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of if there is only one tester or many, it is still a good practice to make use of a test management tool and using a lightweight solution will make you more productive.

There are many benefits over using a static excel file and we recently put together a short blog post which goes into a little detail of the benefits to [organizing your testing process](https://blog.testlodge.com/improve-organize-testing-process/) with a test management tool which may be of interest.

If you are using Mantis to track your issues, you will often find that test management tools integrate with tools like this so that when a test fails a ticket is automatically created and this is a huge time saver.